# How to take heap dump of java application in windows OS manually

Tags: java, heap-dump

How can I take heap dump on windows for any running java application?

Thanks,
Harish

Comment: There is a program called visualm that is packaged with the JDK; it's located in your Java/jdk.../bin/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to take heap dump:

1. Identify process id for java on windows machine using "jps" command through cmd jps like ps command in linux.
2. Use command `jmap -dump:file=mydump <pid_returned_by_jps _command_in_step_1>`
3. You can see mydump file will be created under your users/yourName folder with named mydump